# How to filter ios push notifications before appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Need to hide iOS push notifications after logout from the app. I can handle this when the network connection is available, by sending a logout message to the server.

But if user press logout button while the network connection is not available, the logout message can not be sent to server. The app can queue and send the logout message if the app is running.

But if the user quit app after pressing logout button when the network connection is not available, and connected to internet back, it still receive notifications. Is there any method to handle this scenario?

Comment: You could use Silent Notification, that you manage yourself, deciding to show them or not.

Answer (score 0):

u can use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
```

after you press logout button.

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT**

```
func unregisterForRemoteNotifications()
```

**OBJECTIVE-C**

```
- (void)unregisterForRemoteNotifications
```

> **Discussion**
>   You should call this method in rare circumstances only, such as when a new version of the application drops support for remote notifications. Users can temporarily prevent applications from receiving remote notifications through the Notifications section of the Settings application. Applications unregistered through this method can always re-register.

Your server doesn't get a notification, simply when you call the function, send a data packet to your server and assume the operation was successful. You should also handle this kind of problems on the server, force expire the user session and unregister him from the push service (assuming you have a proper backend)